# Why using ReaderWriterLockSlim doesn't make my Dictionary thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dictionary, readerwriterlockslim

I wrote a small piece of code that rapidly read and write to a dictionary from multiple threads. I used ReaderWriterLockSlim to protect the code and still received an exception for allegedly trying to add duplicate keys.

```
ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
Dictionary<int, int> _dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

public SafeDictionaryTester()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        _dict.Add(i, i);
    }
}

internal void Execute()
{
    for (int i = 7; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        if (i % 6 == 0)
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { Print(6); })).Start();
        else if (i % 5 == 0)
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { Print(5); })).Start();
        else if (i % 4 == 0)
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { Print(4); })).Start();
        else if (i % 3 == 0)
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { Print(3); })).Start();
        else if (i % 2 == 0)
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { Print(2); })).Start();
        else if (i % 1 == 0)
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { Print(1); })).Start();

        new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            _lock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                _dict.Add(i, i); // Exception after random number of loops
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + " added");
            }
            finally
            {
                _lock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        })).Start();
    }
}

private void Print(int i)
{
    _lock.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        int obj;
        if (_dict.TryGetValue(i, out obj))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _lock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
```

Note that the exact code without the threads executes perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ani says, it's got little to do with the dictionary. You really *are* (probably) trying to add the same key twice, because you're capturing the loop variable. The simple fix is to copy the loop variable to a new variable *inside the loop* so that each extra thread will only "see" its own value.

```
for (int i = 7; i < 10000; i++)
{
    // Other stuff...
    copyOfI = i;

    new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
    {
        _lock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            _dict.Add(copyOfI, copyOfI);
            Console.WriteLine(copyOfI.ToString() + " added");
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    })).Start();
}
```

See Eric Lippert's blog posts for more information: [part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx); [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx).

Comment: Your links are more suitable, but I find my link reads better. ;)

Comment: @Jeff: In some ways, I win either way ;)

Comment: Thanks Jon. I've been fooled again by captured variables. Notice that `Print(1)` is not a problem (see the class ctor). **The real question is:** do I need to use locking? Running this test (with different variations) yield no exceptions.

Comment: @HuBeZa: Ah, I hadn't spotted that. Yes, you need to use locking - even if you don't get exceptions, there's no guarantee that you won't be screwing up the internal state. `Dictionary` is simply not safe for multithreaded use unless it's purely for reads. Note that if you're using .NET 4, `ConcurrentDictionary` could be a better bet.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your anonymous writer delegate creates a [closure](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) over `i`.

That is to say, when your writer threads execute, they'll use **the current value** of `i` rather than the value at the time *the thread was started* (7, 8, 9 ... etc.)

To fix it, you need to make a copy of the variable inside your for loop and use that in your writer delegate:

```
internal void Execute()
{
    for (int i = 7; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        // trimmed for brevity: create a copy of i
        int copy = i;

        new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            _lock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                _dict.Add(copy, copy); // Exception after random number of loops
                Console.WriteLine(copy.ToString() + " added");
            }
            finally
            {
                _lock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        })).Start();
    }
```